# How to find the installed Software name and version for the running processes

Tags: c#, process, registry

I have derived the list of current running process based on this code

```
static void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    uint pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (p.Id == pid)
            new TrayLog().Log(
                System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "^" + p.Id + "^" + p.ProcessName + "^" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
            );
    }
}
```

And the list of current installed software are derived based on the below code
    RegistryKey key;

```
// search in: CurrentUser
key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
    try
    {
        if (!subkey.GetValue("DisplayName").Equals(null))
        {
            DataRow rows = dts.NewRow();
            rows["Machine_UUID"] = Machine_UUID;
            rows["Display_Name"] = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString();
            rows["Display_Version"] = subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion").ToString();
            rows["Internal_Version"] = subkey.GetValue("Version").ToString();
            rows["Installation_Date"] = DateTime.ParseExact(subkey.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", null);
            rows["strInstallation_Date"] = ((DateTime)rows["Installation_Date"]).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            rows["Installation_Location"] = subkey.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
            rows["Installation_Source"] = subkey.GetValue("InstallSource").ToString();
            rows["Uninstall_String"] = subkey.GetValue("UninstallString").ToString();
            rows["Estimated_Size"] = subkey.GetValue("EstimatedSize").ToString();
            dts.Rows.Add(rows);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

I need to match these two list, such that I need to get the Software name and other details of the running process...

Comment: Not all running processes will have corresponding Uninstall entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `Process.MainModule.FileName` and then use `FileVersionInfo.FileDescription` to get the display name.

Then use this key, which is a List of all the current installed programs, and their uninstall information.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Now get the display name from the keys and compare them with the process display names.

Comment: Thank you shad0wk, the Process.MainModule is what i expected, but the value retrieved from ProductName and ProductVersion does not match with DisplayName and DisplayVersion of RegistryKey from "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall". Eg: ProductName: Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012 - ProductVersion: 11.0.50727.1 != DisplayName: Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Devenv, DisplayVersion: 11.0.50727

Comment: Maybe you could get the filename, remove the extension, and compare that with the RegistryKey DisplayName as well as. It may get some matches.